# Enlarging or reducing desktop view and making paragraphs

Tags: text

1. I have a Facebook friend who is stating my posts appear huge to her. I use a pc and had thought she had one too. So with little known I told her how to make the text she was seeing smaller by using the Control and - keys. She said it didn't work.
2. She runs all her text together on Facebook so I asked her if she could put paragraph breaks in so I might be able to read her extreme long messages. I use Shift and Enter on my pc.

So how do I tell her how to do this on her Mac?

Answer (score 1):

It should be the same in the Mac, you can also tell her to zoom in [with the trackpad](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204895)

But this looks to be a problem with Facebook itself, according to this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/OutOfTheLoop/comments/4tho5a/why_are_some_facebook_posts_suddenly_in_a_huge/) some posts appear bigger than others because of the number of characters. If they have 35 characters or less, the font size is bigger.

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac you would typically use the <kbd>Command</kbd> key instead of the  <kbd>Control</kbd> key when dealing with many common text keyboard shortcuts.

In terms of the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> keyboard shortcut, that should still work on a Mac.

However, since you're talking about Facebook, it could also be a Facebook formatting issue or related to the specific browser she's using as well.